# SageMaker deep learning gpu docker instance doesn't have CUDA when it should

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, cuda, amazon-sagemaker

I'm currently trying to use [SageMaker Processing](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_processing.html) to run some training and evaluation of some of my PyTorch models on a GPU.

```
from sagemaker.processing import ScriptProcessor

role = 'arn:aws:iam.../service-role/SageMaker-MySageMakerComputeRole'
script_processor = ScriptProcessor(
    command=["python3"],
    image_uri='...dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-processing-container:latest',
    role=role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
)
```

I took a look [here](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/556f8cb94fc9bac32808cdfac33f58b42f109606/available_images.md#sagemaker-framework-containers-sm-support-only) to find the available images for SageMaker. I tried to use both the `-sagemaker` image as well as another image that had a name ending with `-ec2` but neither seemed to run.

```
# tried this
FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.13.1-gpu-py39-cu117-ubuntu20.04-sagemaker
# and also tried this
FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.13.1-gpu-py39-cu117-ubuntu20.04-ec2

WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
...
```

I always seem to get this error from the job logs:

```
2023-06-19T01:48:46.062-07:00 RuntimeError: ('Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you

2023-06-19T01:48:46.062-07:00   have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from

2023-06-19T01:48:46.062-07:00   http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx', "This image doesn't seem to support

2023-06-19T01:48:46.062-07:00   current EC2 instance type, please check release notes for supported EC2 instance

2023-06-19T01:48:46.062-07:00   type")
```

I also ran this in my SageMaker Processing script and it outputted `False` so that corroborates with my error.

```
torch.cuda.is_available() => False
```

I thought the provided images would have CUDA and related dependencies installed. How can I fix/bypass this? Am I using the wrong image or doing some other setup step wrong? I want to be able to run GPU powered workloads on SageMaker. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a PyTorch processor instead of the ScriptProcessor? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/processing-job-frameworks-pytorch.html
Also, you may want to use a GPU instance - you're using a CPU instance (ml.m5.xlarge)

Comment: You are using a non-GPU EC2 instance. Why do you think this code should find a GPU on a system without one?

Comment: I completely fail to see how the selected duplicate has anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an image with support for GPU, and that's fine, but you are using it on an instance type, ml.m5.xlarge that does not have any GPU. You can take a look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/?nc1=h_ls) for a list of available EC2 instances and choose one with a GPU.